# Align text in one line?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I'm having issues trying to get this text displayed on one line, rather then 3 lines.

```
<h2 style="text-align:left">Policy</h2> 
<h2 style="text-align:center">Cart</h2> 
<h2 style="text-align:right">FAQ</h2>
```

The text comes out in separate lines, so that Police is on one line, Cart is on a second line and FAQ is on another line, however they still remain aligned left, center and right.

How would I go about displaying them on the same line but still aligned?

Comment: why didn't you use the list?

<ul>
 <li>Policy</li>
 <li>Cart</li>
 <li>FAQ</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Use list

  <ul class="footer">
     <li>Policy</li>
     <li>Cart</li>
     <li>FAQ</li>
    </ul>

//In the css

    .footer{
      width:100%
      float:left;
    }
    .footer li{
      display:inline;
      margin-right:20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a few things.

First you can add `display: inline-block;` like so,

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or like so,

```
<h2 style="display: inline-block;">Blah Blah</h2>
```

Now you could also float them like so,

```
h2 {
    float: left;
}
```

Or like so,

```
<h2 style="float: left;">Blah Blah</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use float:

```
<h2 style="text-align:left;float:left;">Policy </h2>
<h2 style="text-align:center;float:left;">Cart </h2>
<h2 style="text-align:right;float:left;">FAQ</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a table.

```
<center>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <h2>&nbsp;<a href="put href here">Policy</a>&nbsp;<a href="put href                          here">Cart</a>&nbsp;<a href="put href here">FAQ</a>&nbsp;</h2>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

Comment: Easiest way, add more     &nbsp; if you want.

Comment: Why would you suggest a `table`? This is a terrible solution.

Comment: Yeah it may work but it is not 1990 anymore. `Tables` were never for structure and now that there is tons of different options to use they should never be used for structure.

Answer (score -2):

Use width:500% in css Any percentage according to you based on the padding will work. Try values of percentage of width according to you.... But the width property will work for sure.. That's a guarantee